# Node-gyp error on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, node-gyp

I have repository https://github.com/maximusnikulin/react-gulp-boilerplate

I clone it in a folder on my disk, then I use `npm install` to install all packages.

On Windows 7 it works perfect, but on Windows 10 I have error `node-gyp should be installed with flag -g`, but I have installed it with -g flug several times.

In additional, I installed `VS2015Express` as well as `npm install msvs_version=2015`.

It didn't help.
I will be grateful for any help and advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should type :

`npm install --msvs_version=2015`